# Stream UDP to Android Device using gStreamer Tutorial 3

Tags: udp, gstreamer

Based on the gStreamer Tutorial 3 for Android i'm trying to implement a UDP connection.

On the server side i have a raspberry pi with the following line to start the server.

```
raspivid -t 0 -hf -n -h 480 -w 640 -fps 15 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264sparse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96! gdppay !  udpsink host=192.168.1.1 port=5000
```

On the receiver side i have the tutorial 3 in which i changed the pipeline to the following line.

```
>data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc port=5000 caps=\"application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, payload=96\"  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink", &error);
```

I also included the following plugins:

```
>$(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
```

When i start the app there is a blackscreen with no video or audio.
In Logcat i get an error that H264 and AAC mapping is not possible.

Maybe i have to include sprop-parameter-sets?
And if i have to, how can i easily do that with the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you use *rtph264pay* and *gdppay*.  You should remove *gdppay*.